# Prices, How to hide decimals when are .00?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, price-rules, product-prices, custom-prices

I want to know if exists one elegant option to hide decimals in the price when are ,00 I want this format:

8,45€

299€ ---> Now I have 299,00

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

it will give you the option to cut zero decimals