# Hiding decimals from prices with 00 decimals

Tags: magento2

I need a solution to strip decimals, but **only** from the prices that have ,00 decimals.

```
Example 1:
Price currently showing: € 543,00
Price should show: €543

Example 2:
Price currently showing: €280,95
Price should show: €280,95 (which is good)
```

I've tried multiple Price Formatting extensions, but none seem to do what I want. They're hiding **all** decimals, some even do this by rounding the price. That is not what I need. Does anybody know a working solution? I've been looking for weeks, but can't seem to find a solution.

The solution needs to cover at least category pages and product pages.

Same questions, but accepted solutions are wrong:

- [Remove .00 decimal from price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162419/remove-00-decimal-from-price) (Extension provided in solution hides ALL decimals, not just zeros.)
- [Prices, How to hide decimals when are .00?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70895/prices-how-to-hide-decimals-when-are-00) (Magento 1, not Magento 2. Solution no longer exists anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following files:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js**
(controls the price rendering on product view pages)

**vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php**
(controls rendering of blocks throughout)

In the **Amount.php** file you'll find this function:

```
public function formatCurrency(
    $amount,
    $includeContainer = true,
    $precision = PriceCurrencyInterface::DEFAULT_PRECISION
) {
    return $this->priceCurrency->format($amount, $includeContainer, $precision);
}
```

We need to write a plugin to override this function:

1. your custom module **etc/di.xml**

[image]

2. Vendor\Module\Pricing\Amount.php

   ```
    /**
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Format price value
     *
     * @param float $amount
     * @param bool $includeContainer
     * @param int $precision
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterFormatCurrency(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $subject, $result)
    {
      $amount = $subject->getAmount()->getValue();
      $includeContainer = true;
      $precision = null;
        if (floor($amount) == $amount) {
          return $this->priceCurrency->format($amount, $includeContainer, $precision = 0);
        }
        return $result;
    }
   ```

This should change price block output throughout (category, related, etc).

But, back to the first file - this will change the product view page back to a format with .00, so we also need to update this file too.

In **function formatPrice** of price-utils.js you will find below line

```
precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
```

Update this to

```
if (Number.isInteger(amount)) {
  precision = 0;
} else {
  precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
}
```

We can make this change using mixin.
**view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
config: {
        mixins: {
          'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/price-utils': true
          }
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/web/js/price-utils.js**

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore'
   ],
    function ($, _) {
        'use strict';

        var globalPriceFormat = {
            requiredPrecision: 2,
            integerRequired: 1,
            decimalSymbol: ',',
            groupSymbol: ',',
            groupLength: ','
        };

        return function (target) {

          function stringPad(string, times) {
              return (new Array(times + 1)).join(string);
          }

            target.formatPrice = function formatPrice(amount, format, isShowSign) {
              var s = '',
                  precision, integerRequired, decimalSymbol, groupSymbol, groupLength, pattern, i, pad, j, re, r, am;

              format = _.extend(globalPriceFormat, format);

              // copied from price-option.js | Could be refactored with varien/js.js
              if (Number.isInteger(amount)) {
                precision = 0;
              } else {
                precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
              }

              integerRequired = isNaN(format.integerRequired = Math.abs(format.integerRequired)) ? 1 : format.integerRequired;
              decimalSymbol = format.decimalSymbol === undefined ? ',' : format.decimalSymbol;
              groupSymbol = format.groupSymbol === undefined ? '.' : format.groupSymbol;
              groupLength = format.groupLength === undefined ? 3 : format.groupLength;
              pattern = format.pattern || '%s';

              if (isShowSign === undefined || isShowSign === true) {
                  s = amount < 0 ? '-' : isShowSign ? '+' : '';
              } else if (isShowSign === false) {
                  s = '';
              }
              pattern = pattern.indexOf('{sign}') < 0 ? s + pattern : pattern.replace('{sign}', s);

              // we're avoiding the usage of to fixed, and using round instead with the e representation to address
              // numbers like 1.005 = 1.01. Using ToFixed to only provide trailing zeroes in case we have a whole number
              i = parseInt(
                      amount = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(+amount || 0) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision)),
                      10
                  ) + '';
              pad = i.length < integerRequired ? integerRequired - i.length : 0;

              i = stringPad('0', pad) + i;

              j = i.length > groupLength ? i.length % groupLength : 0;
              re = new RegExp('(\\d{' + groupLength + '})(?=\\d)', 'g');

              // replace(/-/, 0) is only for fixing Safari bug which appears
              // when Math.abs(0).toFixed() executed on '0' number.
              // Result is '0.-0' :(

              am = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(amount - i) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision));
              r = (j ? i.substr(0, j) + groupSymbol : '') +
                  i.substr(j).replace(re, '$1' + groupSymbol) +
                  (precision ? decimalSymbol + am.toFixed(precision).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : '');

              return pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
            };

            return target;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear information. I'll give this a try tomorrow or the day after, and let you know!

Comment: I updated my answer as you should use plugin method to override the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly the information I needed!